# typo3 news realurl overwriteDemand

Tags: typo3, fluid, realurl

I am using Typo3 7.1 + Fluid(Latest Integrated with 7.1) and I am very new to this latest version.

Added News plugin(tx_news) and using Categories. Categories are left menu and located in News List page as well as News Detail page.

I am getting url look like this,

http://domain.com/de/sample/?tx_news_pi1%5BoverwriteDemand%5D%5Bcategories%5D=5&cHash=8aa8fd1fb7a5e47165a4e4acca3125e9

I don't know where I am doing mistake, I just wanted url like this, http://domain.com/de/sample/.

It is really helpful when anyone explain. Thanks in advance.

My Typoscript Settings in urltoolconf_realurl.php are,

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array ( 
    '_DEFAULT' => array (
        'init' => array (
            'enableCHashCache' => '1',
            'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile',
            'enableUrlDecodeCache' => '1',
            'enableUrlEncodeCache' => '1',
        ),
        'redirects' => array (
        ),
        'preVars' => array (
            '0' => array (
                'GETvar' => 'no_cache',
                'valueMap' => array (
                    'nc' => '1',
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass'
            ),
            '1' => array (
                'GETvar' => 'L',
                'valueMap' => array (
                    'de' => '0',
                    'en' => '1',
                    'cs' => '2'
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass'
            ),
            '2' => array (
                'GETvar' => 'lang',
                'valueMap' => array (
                    'de' => 'de',
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass',
            ),
        ),
        'pagePath' => array (
            'type' => 'user',
            'userFunc' => 'EXT:realurl/class.tx_realurl_advanced.php:&tx_realurl_advanced->main',
            'spaceCharacter' => '-',
            'languageGetVar' => 'L',
            'expireDays' => '7',
        ),
        'fixedPostVars' => array (
        'newsDetailConfiguration' => array(
array(
'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
'valueMap' => array(
'detail' => '',
),
'noMatch' => 'bypass'
),
array(
'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
'valueMap' => array(
'Legamaster' => '',
),
'noMatch' => 'bypass'
),
array(
'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
'lookUpTable' => array(
'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
'id_field' => 'uid',
'alias_field' => 'title',
'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
'useUniqueCache' => 1,
'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
'strtolower' => 1,
'spaceCharacter' => '-'
),
'languageGetVar' => 'L',
'languageExceptionUids' => '',
'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
'autoUpdate' => 1,
'expireDays' => 180,
)
)
),
'newsCategoryConfiguration' => array(
array(
'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][categories]',
'lookUpTable' => array(
'table' => 'sys_category',
'id_field' => 'uid',
'alias_field' => 'title',
'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
'useUniqueCache' => 1,
'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
'strtolower' => 1,
'spaceCharacter' => '-'
)
)
)
),
'newsTagConfiguration' => array(
array(
'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][tags]',
'lookUpTable' => array(
'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_tag',
'id_field' => 'uid',
'alias_field' => 'title',
'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
'useUniqueCache' => 1,
'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
'strtolower' => 1,
'spaceCharacter' => '-'
)
)
)
),
),
'postVarSets' => array (
            '_DEFAULT' => array (
                'article' => array(
                    array(
                            'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
                            'noMatch' => 'bypass'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
                        'noMatch' => 'bypass'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[year]',
                    ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try add

```
'fixedPostVars' => array(
...
                '35' => 'newsDetailConfiguration', #change you id page with news detail plugin
                '79' => 'newsTagConfiguration', # change you id page with news tag plugin if need
                #'69' => 'newsCategoryConfiguration', # change you id page with news category plugin
),
```

Comment: your suggestions are more helpful. I just made small changes in day, month and year according to my needings and also added your solutions and finally it works. Thanks.

Comment: Hello #Oleg in my case: category and tags plugin in same page means uid is same like: '79' => 'newsDetailConfiguration',  '6' => 'newsCategoryConfiguration',   '6' => 'newsTagConfiguration', it'll replace index. your single line help made day :) thanks.

Comment: In this case I use AJAX with custom filter (Category, Tags, Dates) and Search Form Search result to show my news. If you interest i can send you example In this case I use AJAX with custom filter (Category, Tags, Date) and Search Form + Search result to show my news. If you interest i can send you example like http://hess.typozone.com/aktuelles/